# Using webclient with htmlAgilityPack on wp7 to get html generated from javascript

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient, windows-phone-7.1, html-agility-pack

i want to get the time schedule on

http://www.21cineplex.com/playnow/sherlock-holmes-a-game-of-shadows,2709.htm

first, 
i have tried using webclient with htmlAgilityPack and get to the table id = "table-theater" but appearently the html generated from java script so the table innetHTML is empty.

```
        public void LoadMovieShowTime(string MovieLink)
    {
        WebClient MovieShowTimeclient = new WebClient();
        MovieShowTimeclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(MovieLink));
        MovieShowTimeclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(MovieShowTimeclient_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }
    void MovieShowTimeclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(e.Result);

        var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").First()
            .Elements("div").Skip(1).First()
            .Elements("div").Skip(1).First()
            .Element("div")
            .Elements("table").FirstOrDefault(table => table.Attributes["class"].Value == "table-theater");
    }
```

Is it possible to get the data using webclient on windows phone? or is there any pssible way to get it using another method?

second,
i have tried to get the time schedule from mobile site which is

http://m.21cineplex.com/gui.list_schedule?sid=&movie_id=11SHGO&find_by=1&order=1

but the return ask me to enable cookies. im new to this, i find that there is a way to extend webclien ability by overriding the webRequest cookies, but cant find any reference how to use it.

thanks, for any reply and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the table is generated in JavaScript does not mean the WebBrowser control will not render it. Ensure that [IsScriptEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is set to true, this will ensure that the JavaScript that renders the table is executed. You can then 'scrape' the results.

Comment: webclient doesnt behave like webcontrol, it dont render JavaScript. is it possible to get the html from webBrowser control? can you explain? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can get the html from the web browser control as a string. I would use a hidden web browser to fetch and render the page.

Comment: exactly what i do now. but havent found it yet

Comment: SaveToString http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.savetostring(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: thankss! :)) one more question, why is the address back to the base address "http://www.21cineplex.com" instead of the one that injected? on webClient the address dont comeback to the base address. thank you

Comment: sorry but the address is change on webbrowser :(